# React y biblioteca react-leaflet texto bajo marcadores

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, leaflet

Estoy haciendo un mapa en React utilizando la biblioteca react-leaflet y me gustaría que bajo cada marcador apareciese el nombre de cada uno de ellos. Cuando los he añadido, me aparecen todos apelotonados arriba y detrás del mapa. Cuando quiero moverlos con el CSS se mueven juntos, no bajo cada marcador. Dejo el código:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import markers from '../data/markersDB';
import '../styles/MapView.css'

const MapView = () => {
  const defaultPosition = [37.561445006310464, -5.83284403268617];
  return (
    <MapContainer center={defaultPosition} zoom={9}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            />

            {markers.map(({ id, geocode, name, capacity, reserva, porcentaje }) => (
                <Marker className="marker" key={id} position={geocode}>
                    <div className="marker-name">{name}</div>
                    <Popup className='popup' autoOpen={true}>
                        <p className="popup__name">{name}</p>
                        <p className="popup__information">Capacidad: {capacity} hm³</p>
                        <p className="popup__information">Reserva: {reserva} hm³</p>
                        <p className="popup__information">Porcentaje: {porcentaje}</p>
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
            ))}
        </MapContainer>
  )
}

export default MapView
```

Este es el CSS que he intentado utilizar

```
.popup__name {
  text-align: center;
}

.marker {
  position: relative;
}

.marker-name {
  position: bottom;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Dejo también una captura de pantalla para que podáis ver mejor a lo que me refiero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda